# Use multiAddress.enabled in zookeeper to specify multiple address

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am trying to add multiple addresses for the zookeeper
as per docs, adding the following configuration should be enough

```
multiAddress.enabled=true
server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.2=192.168.1.100:2888:3888 | 192.168.1.101:2889:3889
```

but after adding the following, I get the error message

```
org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException: Multiple address feature is disabled, but multiple addresses were specified for sid 2
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer$QuorumServer.initializeWithAddressString(QuorumPeer.java:327)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer$QuorumServer.<init>(QuorumPeer.java:278)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer$QuorumServer.<init>(QuorumPeer.java:273)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.flexible.QuorumMaj.<init>(QuorumMaj.java:92)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.createQuorumVerifier(QuorumPeerConfig.java:658)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parseDynamicConfig(QuorumPeerConfig.java:689)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.setupQuorumPeerConfig(QuorumPeerConfig.java:663)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parseProperties(QuorumPeerConfig.java:491)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:194)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:125)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:91)
Invalid config, exiting abnormally
```

looked in the zookeeper code: https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/zookeeper-server/src/main/java/org/apache/zookeeper/server/quorum/QuorumPeer.java  line 327, it checks for the similar key **zookeeper.multiAddress.enabled** but still evaluates multiAddress.enabled to false

DOCS REFERENCE: https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.1/zookeeperAdmin.html

```
server.x=[hostname]:nnnnn[:nnnnn] etc : (No Java system property) servers making up the ZooKeeper ensemble. When the server starts up, it determines which server it is by looking for the file myid in the data directory. That file contains the server number, in ASCII, and it should match x in server.x in the left hand side of this setting. The list of servers that make up ZooKeeper servers that is used by the clients must match the list of ZooKeeper servers that each ZooKeeper server has. There are two port numbers nnnnn. The first followers use to connect to the leader, and the second is for leader election. If you want to test multiple servers on a single machine, then different ports can be used for each server.
Since ZooKeeper 3.6.0 it is possible to specify multiple addresses for each ZooKeeper server (see ZOOKEEPER-3188). To enable this feature, you must set the multiAddress.enabled configuration property to true. This helps to increase availability and adds network level resiliency to ZooKeeper. When multiple physical network interfaces are used for the servers, ZooKeeper is able to bind on all interfaces and runtime switching to a working interface in case a network error. The different addresses can be specified in the config using a pipe ('|') character. A valid configuration using multiple addresses looks like:

server.1=zoo1-net1:2888:3888|zoo1-net2:2889:3889
server.2=zoo2-net1:2888:3888|zoo2-net2:2889:3889
server.3=zoo3-net1:2888:3888|zoo3-net2:2889:3889
```

Answer (score 0):

**multiAddress.enabled** is **java system property**, not configed in **zoo.cfg**

you can add ***-Dzookeeper.multiAddress.enabled=true*** to zkServer.sh somewhere, when you can grep from ps, it will take effect

e.g.:

```
# ps -elf | grep java | grep multiAddress
0 S root      6973     1  0  80   0 - 1209436 futex_ 14:59 pts/0  00:00:04 java -Dzookeeper.log.dir=/root/apache-zookeeper-3.8.0-bin/bin/../logs -Dzookeeper.log.file=zookeeper-root-server-dev91.log -Dzookeeper.multiAddress.enabled=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError ...
```